# Spring Boot ReactiveRedis custom annotation to subscribe the channel and get the data

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-data-redis

I am working on spring boot ReactiveRedis for the **pub-sub mechanism** following is my code and it is working fine, I am getting data in **subscribe call back**.

```
@Autowired
private ReactiveRedisOperations<String, Object> reactiveRedisTemplate;
 
@PostConstruct
    public void init(){
        System.out.println("*****SampleLoader***** initialized - SampleLoader");

        this.reactiveRedisTemplate.listenTo(ChannelTopic.of("some-topic")).subscribe(data -> {
                System.out.println(
                        "data.getChannel():-" + data.getChannel() + ":" + "data.getMessage():-" + data.getMessage());
        });
    }
```

But my question is how to create a custom annotation like

```
@Target({ ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.ANNOTATION_TYPE })
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@MessageMapping
@Documented
@Repeatable(RedisListeners.class)
public @interface RedisListener{
}

@Target({ ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.ANNOTATION_TYPE })
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
public @interface RedisListeners {

    RedisListener[] value();

}


  @RedisListener("some-topic")
        public void redisData(String channel, Object data){
        
        }
```

**@RedisListener** will subscribe to the topic and return the call-back data.

Answer (score 1):

1. Obtain all methods of adding annotation RedisListener through scanning
2. Get the values of the annotation, and listen to these topics through the reactiveRedisTemplate
3. Call the method through reflection in the callback method